# How to check for each row in subquery in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table **PrivateIPAddress** with the following data

| id | ipAddress | ipAddressTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.0.0.0 | 10.255.255.255 |
| 2 | 172.16.0.0 | 172.31.255.255 |
| 3 | 192.168.0.0 | 192.168.255.255 |

I need to find if an IP address is external or internal. To find an IP address as internal, the IP address that I give as an input should fall within any of the higher and lower bounds given in the table PrivateIPAddress. ie., **10.70.10.1** falls within the higher and lower bounds (**ipAddress** and **ipAddressTo**) of first row in the table.

I tried different queries, but none of them worked.

```
SELECT (INET_ATON('10.70.10.1') >= ANY (select inet_aton(ipAddress) from PrivateIPAddress) OR INET_ATON('10.70.10.1') <= ANY (select inet_aton(ipAddressTo) from PrivateIPAddress));
```

The above query will not check for each row seperately, which is why it is failing. The inet_aton function converts the IP address to an integer which helps me in checking if it is within an ip range.

Can anyone suggest a better alternative to get the required result ?

Comment: Add two generated columns which converts textual IP address to binary representation. Do the same with the address to test.Do not test the boundaries separately, use BETWEEN operator.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but the problem is with writing the query. How can I check for all the rows separately in a single step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select case count(*) 
when 1 then 'private address'
when 0 then 'public address'
end as 'type of address' 
from  PrivateIPAddress where inet_aton('172.16.3.1') between inet_aton(ipAddress) and inet_aton(ipAddressTo);
-- result: private address

select case count(*) 
when 1 then 'private address'
when 0 then 'public address'
end as 'type of address' 
from  PrivateIPAddress where inet_aton('162.16.3.1') between inet_aton(ipAddress) and inet_aton(ipAddressTo);
-- result: public address
```